# Suggestions for diary software glue?

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

I'm looking to use my Ubuntu Xenial machine to keep a personal diary. I have looked into Red Notebook and Lifeograph (parametric tags are cool!) for this purpose but they don't totally fit my needs. I'm wondering what suggestions people have for how to do the below, the original idea comes from a sort of "Captain's Log" one would keep if they were a character in a Star Trek episode. I have experience with the command-line, compiling source code, and virtual machines, so I'm open to doing some work if the idea is right.

My pie-in-the-sky version of this is that I record a video diary through the webcam, I can transcribe it in some way, and store the text files next to the video files as transcripts. I would have a directory structure so I could search it with a search tool or manually by going to a particular year/month/day. I realize this is a little unrealistic so I settled on a slightly easier plan (below).

I have settled on flat text files and accompanying video entries in a folder with accompanying filesystem structure (easy enough). I will also keep a LibreOffice Calc spreadheet of various metrics (miles walked, calories consumed, etc) which I can then use to make graphs and other fancy images.

I would love some suggestions for combinations of software that could make this job easier. Do you know of software for tracking stats that might make this process more seamless? For example, instead of manually generating a graph in calc, I just input the data and it makes graphs pretty automatically?

Here's my requirements:

- Journal entries stored in an open and relatively future-proof format, ie no diary software that has been around for 2-3 years which stores everything in one large binary file that only that software can interpret. Currently using plain-text for this
- Metrics kept with a software to track daily life stats so I can use them to generate graphs like "miles walked per month". Currently using calc for this.
- Webcam software that takes a picture or video and automatically saves it into a folder with the correct date ie diary/2017/march/17. Currently using cheese for this though it can't save to folders with variables in the name.

I have been researching this for about a week, doesn't seem to be a lot out there aside from basic diary software, would love if you all had some interesting ideas for this project. Thanks!